# Suppose that $K_1(x,y)$ and $K_2(x,y)$ are valid kernels prove that $K_1(x,y)K_2(x,y)$ is a valid kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, machine-learning

Suppose that $K_1(x,y)$ and $K_2(x,y)$ are valid kernels meaning that the can be expressed in the form of 
\begin{align*}
K_1(x,y) = \phi_1(x)^\top \phi_1(y) 
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\phi_1(x)_i \phi_1(y)_i\\
K_2(x,y) = \phi_2(x)^\top \phi_2(y) 
\end{align*}
(source: [Wikipedia: Kernel Method, paragraph "the kernel trick"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method))

Prove that $K_1(x,y)K_2(x,y)$ is a valid kernel.

The following derivation is given:
\begin{align*}
K_1(x,y) = \phi_1(x)^\top \phi_1(y) 
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\phi_1(x)_i \phi_1(y)_i\\
K_2(x,y) = \phi_2(x)^\top \phi_2(y) 
&= \sum_{j = 1}^m\phi_2(x)_j \phi_2(y)_j\\
K_1(x,y)K_2(x,y) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n\phi_1(x)_i \phi_1(y)_i\sum_{j = 1}^m\phi_2(x)_j \phi_2(y)_j\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^m\big[\phi_1(x)_i \phi_1(y)_i\big]\big[\phi_2(x)_j \phi_2(y)_j\big]\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^m\big[\phi_1(x)_i \phi_2(x)_j\big]\big[\phi_1(y)_i \phi_2(y)_j\big]\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{mn}\phi_{12}(x)_k \phi_{12}(y)_k\\
&= \phi_{12}(x)^\top \phi_{12}(y)\\
\end{align*}

**Edit (This chunk is probably wrong but left as originally posted in order to be able to understand the comments... in case...)**

However, I think there are 2 issues with this notation

- to me, as $n = m$, we can replace $m$ by $n$
- moreover, to me
  $$
  \phi_{12}(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n\phi_1(x)_i \phi_2(y)_i =  \phi_1(x)^\top \phi_2(y)
  $$

hence the whole derivation should be written as
\begin{align*}
K_1(x,y) = \phi_1(x)^\top \phi_1(y) 
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\phi_1(x)_i \phi_1(y)_i\\
K_2(x,y) = \phi_2(x)^\top \phi_2(y) 
&= \sum_{j = 1}^{\color{red}n}\phi_2(x)_j \phi_2(y)_j\\
K_1(x,y)K_2(x,y) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n\phi_1(x)_i \phi_1(y)_i\sum_{j = 1}^m\phi_2(x)_j \phi_2(y)_j\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^{\color{red}n}\big[\phi_1(x)_i \phi_1(y)_i\big]\big[\phi_2(x)_j \phi_2(y)_j\big]\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^{\color{red}n}\big[\phi_1(x)_i \phi_2(x)_j\big]\big[\phi_1(y)_i \phi_2(y)_j\big]\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{\color{blue}n}\phi_{12}(x)_k \phi_{12}(y)_k\\
&= \phi_{12}(x)^\top \phi_{12}(y)\\
\end{align*}
What's correct?

**Edit (and Answer, thanks to @GReyes)**

where

- the definition of $\phi_{12}$ is:
  \begin{align*}
  \phi_{12}(x)_k &= \phi_1(x)_i\phi_2(x)_j\\
  \phi_{12}(x)&= \begin{bmatrix}
  \phi_{12}(x)_1, ..., \phi_{12}(x)_k
  \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align*}
  where 
  \begin{align*}
  &\phi_{12}(x)_s = \phi_{1}(x)_i\phi_{2}(x)_j\\
  &i \in \{1, ..., n\}\\
  &j \in \{1, ..., m\}\\
  &s \in \{1, ..., k\}\\
  &k = nm
  \end{align*}
- As $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ can map to different spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. Hence $n=m$ and $n\ne m$ are both possible. Hence,  $n\ne m$, $\phi_{12}$ itself cannot be expressed as a dot product

Comment: The notion of "valid kernel" is not entirely standard... Could you explain the context a little more fully?

Comment: I think that you do not need $m=n$. Your kernels mimic a mapping into different spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. The resulting kernel corresponds to a mapping to $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$. All you need is symmetry and positive definiteness (Mercier’s Theorem).

Comment: @paulgarrett I added the definition and the source

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem for a bunch of proofs.

Comment: @GReyes If the kernels map into different spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, how would you then define the function $\phi_{12}$ or the dot product between the result of those 2 functions ($\phi_1^\top\phi(x)_2$)

Comment: There are $mn$ components in $\phi_{12}$ since it is obtained by multiplying each component of $\phi_1$ with each component of $\phi_2$. In your last sum the index should go from 1 to $mn$ So this is a dot product in $mn$ dimensions

Comment: Thank you for your many Feedbacks @GReyes. My way of interpreting $\phi_{12}$ is the following is the following: $\phi_{12}(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n\phi_1(x)_i \phi_2(y)_i =  \phi_1(x)^\top \phi_2(y)$. So for me the dot product is already contained in the function. In the expression $\phi_{12}(x)^\top \phi_{12}(y)$ is another dot product but if we write $\phi_{12}(x)^\top \phi_{12}(y) = \sum_{k = 1}^{nm} = \phi_{12}(x)_k^\top \phi_{12}_k$, wouldn't it mean doing a dot product one additional time (one too much time)?

Comment: Once you get to the expression $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^m\phi_1(x)_i\phi_2(x)_j\phi_1(y)_i\phi_2(y)_j$ (and I think you agree with this because of your comments) you are free to interpret it as you want. A way is by defining $\phi_{12,k}=\phi_{1,i}\phi_{2,j}$ for each $k=1,2,\dots mn$ and each possible combination of $i$ and $j$. For ex, if $n=2$, $m=2$ then you call $\phi_{12,1}=\phi_{1,1}\phi_{2,1}$, $\phi_{12,2}=\phi_{1,1}\phi_{2,2}$ etc, all the four combinations. Then you get $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{mn}\phi_{12,k}(x)\sum\phi_{12,k}(y)$ which is a dot product in $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$.

Comment: Alright!!!!!! I think/hope I get it now (although sometimes I think I get it although I actually didn't or I forget the understanding and I have to understand it again...). Many thanks for your patient @GReyes

Comment: @GReyes I edited the question with the answer thanks to your help. Please tell me if you think it still contains errors.

Comment: Ok great. Glad to have helped. However, I do not think the second expression (that for $\phi_{`2}$) is correct. $\phi_{12}$ is actually a vector $\phi_{12}(x,y)=(\phi_{1,1}(x)\phi_{2,1}(y), \phi_{1,1}(x)\phi_{2,2}(y),\dots \phi_{1,n}(x)\phi_{2,m}(y))$ with a total of  $mn$ components.

Comment: @GReyes, you're right again. I changed again the definition of $\phi_{12}$. I hope it is correct now

Comment: Sounds right to me now. Cheers.